# Redirect to different url in aspx application

Tags: asp.net

I am redirecting to a different url in my application using below code on aspx page.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML Meta Tag</title>
  <meta http-equiv = "refresh" 
   content = "2; url = 
  https://www.tutorialspoint.com" />
```

I want to read the url from config file here but no success. Its not taking the arguments here to read from the config file. Can anyone educate here if anyone knows a way here??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the code behind Response.Redirect(url); To grab a url in a web.config file just call it with

```
  string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlKeyName"].ToString();

   Response.Redirect(url);
```